# How to upgrade TeXLive binaries

Tags: luatex, texlive-2016

What is a recommended way to upgrade the TeXLive binaries, specifically, LuaTeX to v. 1.0 in TeXLive 2016? Is there a repository similar to MiKTeX Next?

Comment: The best option is to install from http://www.tug.org/texlive/

Comment: @Sigur As far as I know, binaries updates are not provided through tug.org. Am I wrong?

Comment: Do you want [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/106162)

Comment: No, I want to update a binary, not a package, as discussed there.

Comment: There's  a reason the TL team avoid updating binaries during the year: it's often non-trivial. If you are on Windows life is relatively easy as W32TeX provides the binaries for TL and does have 'drop in' versions of several things, but unless you are doing hard-core development this is probably not necessary ...